# Finding all possible values of a Function

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, number-theory, functions

> Let a function be defined as $f:N\to N$ and $x-f(x)= 19\left[\dfrac{x}{19}\right] - 90\left[\dfrac{f(x)}{90}\right] \forall x\in \Bbb N$ and $1900<f(1990)<2000$. Find all values of $f(1990)$.

$$$$
I really have no clue as to how to go about this as I've never encountered such questions before. I would be truly grateful if somebody would please show me how to solve this question.$$$$
Many thanks in anticipation!

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere? The only value I can see for $f(1990)$ is 14. Putting $x=1990$ in the equation you have  $14+\lfloor\frac{f(x)}{90}\rfloor=f(x)$.

Comment: maybe the given should have $90 \lfloor\frac{f(x)}{90}\rfloor$ instead of $\lfloor\frac{f(x)}{90}\rfloor$

Comment: @almagest Sorry Sir, there was indeed a typing error; the same as user Lozenges pointed out

Comment: @Lozenges Yes, Sir, you were right.

Answer (score 2):

Putting $x=1990$ in the given equation we have $\frac{14}{90}=\frac{f(x)}{90}-\lfloor\frac{f(x)}{90}\rfloor$. Hence $f(x)=14\bmod90$, so $x=1904$ or $1994$.

Answer (score 0):

As $1900<f(1990)<2000$,

we have $90[\frac{f(1990)}{90}]=90*22=1980$.

Moreover, we have $19[\frac{1990}{19}]=1976$, and so $x-19[\frac{x}{19}]=14$, for $x=1990$.

Now, from your equation, we have $f(x)= x-19[\frac{x}{19}]+[\frac{f(x)}{90}]$,

and so $f(1990)=14+1980=1994$. This seems to be the only value.

Comment: kindly note that there was a typing error which i've mentioned in my comments above.

Comment: No problem, I edited the answer according to your correction of the problem. Now, there is not contradiction.